# Using Yubico YubiKey 5 NFC for local data encryption

Tags: disk-encryption, yubikey

I'm interested in buying a Yubikey  but want to know if you can use a Yubikey to generate a symmetric key for file encryption on selected files on a PC. Or if you need some sort of extension like HMAC-secret to do so with a Yubikey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can generate or store a GPG key on the YubiKey, then encrypt and decrypt files using gpg."

https://www.reddit.com/r/yubikey/comments/q315bo/file_encryption_with_yubikey/

Comment: I see, thx for the link!